# Outlined characters

Tags: fonts, characters

How could I produce characters which are outlined when the character itself is in some color. A picture to illustrate what I'm after:
[image]

The problems with the above are that:

- the outline is of no consistent width around the letter.
- the way I've done it (using tikz with a upscaled black node below the colored one), there is no easy way to control the width of the outline.

Do you know of a way to accomplish this with TeX? I am using plain-format with XeTeX, but I'm interested in all ways to accomplish this.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/85694/86

Comment: Also related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96766/writing-practice-sheets-dotted-letters/97098

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [pst-text](http://ctan.org/pkg/pst-text) package can do this.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pst-text}
\DeclareFixedFont{\RM}{T1}{ptm}{b}{n}{2cm}

\begin{document}
  \pscharpath[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=magenta!50]{\RM TeXnik}
\end{document}
```

Perhaps you can migrate this to plain (Xe)TeX.

---

[image]

Comment: +1 but text-search will be no longer possible. :-)

Comment: Since the OP used tikZ this should be no major problem.

Comment: I don't get the same output (no color) with the example.

Comment: I don't get the effect show in the image either!

Answer (score 28):

The [contour package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/contour) can do this, too. 
You'll need to use Type 1 fonts (check the documentation); here is sample code

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pslatex}
\usepackage{contour}
\usepackage{color}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\contourlength{2pt} %how thick each copy is
\contournumber{20}  %number of copies
\contour{red}{\Huge \textcolor{green}{This is the text.}}\\
\end{document}
```

The output is: [image]
Changing the contourlength to 1pt will give a less pronounced outline.

Comment: What did the log file say was the problem?

Comment: With a minimal: `\input eplain \beginpackages\usepackage{contour}\endpackages bar\bye`, I get: `Undefined control sequence. \newlength`

Comment: When I put "minimal" into the documentclass, instead of "article" I get an "Undefined control sequence" error. It was fixed by removing "\Huge" from the code. If that doesn't work, maybe try to find a minimal example that doesn't work and repost as question?

Comment: Oh, right, so... There is the language TeX, and then there are *macro-packages* which build up on the primitives provided by the language: plain-tex, latex, and context, for example. I am using the plain-tex macro-package, for which there exists a macro-collection called eplain which allows loading *some* macro-packages designed to work with latex, to be loaded in plain-tex. I didn't realize you could load eplain with latex.

Comment: You should specify `\textcolor{}{}` *outside* the contour, at least in Beamer. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78386/outlined-characters-in-beamer.

Comment: Very nice, but I don't get word wrap when applied to multiline text, am I missing something?

Comment: "Minimal" document class is designed for testing class loading dependencies: it defines page size and normal font size, and that's it, nothing else. It is not intended for Minimal Working Examples. For MWEs, use a normal class, like 'article', or whatever is relevant to the question.

Answer (score 15):

Package `pdfrender` for pdfTeX or LuaTeX (newer versions require package `luatex85`) allows to configure the outline with many parameters as fill color,
stroke color, or line width for stroking.

Because of pdfTeX's colorstacks, page breaks are supported as for color settings.

Example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
% \usepackage{luatex85} % for LuaTeX
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdfrender}
\definecolor{CharFillColor}{rgb}{1,.8,.8}
\begin{document}
  \sffamily
  \textpdfrender{
    TextRenderingMode=FillStroke,
    LineWidth=.2pt,
    FillColor=CharFillColor,
  }{Lorem ipsum.}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: I have found that for some fonts such as `\usepackage{Oswald}`, when outlining large bold characters some lines get "overdrawn", which I was able to solve by setting `  MiterLimit=1` [reference image](https://imgur.com/NsdzGR0). No clue what it does tho, the option is not further explained in the package documentation.

Comment: @Hyperplane "Miter Limit" is explained in the PDF reference, see section "Details of Graphics State Parameters".

Answer (score 10):

Some years later, in a file I found called [“Practical use of special commands in DVIPDFMx” by Jin-Hwan Cho](http://project.ktug.org/dvipdfmx/doc/tug2005.pdf) (TUG2005), I found information on the low-level PDF command for use with dvipdfmx:

```
\special{pdf:bcolor [.8 0 .8] [0]} % two arrays: first defines fill, second the stroke.
% If array has one entry, it's meaning grayscale, if three: RGB, if four: CMYK.
\special{pdf:literal direct .4 w 2 Tr} % .4 here is the stroke width
F
\bye
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know any good resources where I can learn more about these PDF literals?

Comment: @Henri: You can find the document I'm talking about in the answer [here](http://project.ktug.org/dvipdfmx/doc/tug2005.pdf), and for the PDF reference, you can see [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html). I think I also remember some talks related to PStricks which also cover some of the PDF subset, but I don't have any links for you now; sorry.