# Outlined characters in Beamer

Tags: beamer, formatting, text-decorations

Following [Outlined characters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25221/outlined-characters/25241#25241), you can make selectable outlined text using the `contour` package. For example, the following writes "Text text text contour text", with "contour" in green with a red outline. It compiles and displays as expected (using `pdflatex` and `lualatex`):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\begin{document}
Text text text \contour{red}{\textcolor{green}{contour}} text.
\end{document}
```

However, when I try to do the same in a Beamer presentation—

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Example}
Text text text \contour{red}{\textcolor{green}{contour}} text.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

—it fails to compile, with the error

```
! Use of \\@contour doesn't match its definition.
\beamer@ifnextcharospec #1#2->\def \reserved@a {
                                                #1}\def \reserved@b {#2}\fut...
l.14 \end{frame}

?
```

How can I use the outline effect in a Beamer presentation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Prolog

Apparently, `beamer` redefines `\textcolor` in a way that makes it fragile.

If you `\usepackage{beamerarticle}` in your `article` MWE, you experience the same problems as with `beamer`.

## Long answer

[What is the difference between Fragile and Robust commands?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4736/what-is-the-difference-between-fragile-and-robust-commands)

## Short answer

Use

- `\contour{<color>}{\protect\textcolor{<color>}{<text>}}` or
- `\textcolor{<color>}{\contour{<color>}{<text>}}`.

### Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Example}
Text text text \contour{red}{\protect\textcolor{green}{contour}} text. \\
Text text text \textcolor{green}{\contour{red}{contour}} text.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image: Output]

Comment: That does work. Any idea why the error occurs though, and why only with Beamer?

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail I've updated my answer which now, hopefully, gives more insight.

Comment: Is there a way to change the contour size?