# Adding contour to the characters

Tags: characters

I was wondering whether it is possible to highlight the contour of the characters with tex like in the following picture:

[image]

Or like in Allen Hatcher's 'Algebraic Topology': http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf

Any idea is will be very useful. Thank you very much!

Comment: Did you see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25221/outlined-characters?

Comment: I know you want to replicate it but please don't do this especially in a book. It is ugly.

Comment: Thank you very much for both comments! It is just what I needed.