# Military stencil alphabet style

Tags: letters

In movies and on military issues one can see stencil letters. Although I don't want to write a whole text in this style I am asking myself if there is a LaTeX package for writing in military stencil letter style?

Comment: If you have the font, you can compile using xelatex.

Comment: There are hundreds, if  not thousands or even tens of thousands, of stencil-type fonts available for download from the Internet. Please narrow down the list of fonts you may be interested in. Separately, have you looked into using either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX instead of pdfLaTeX? The former two make it easy to use commercially available fonts (assuming, of course, that you've downloaded and activated the fonts in a way that's appropriate for your computer system).

Comment: I'm not aware of a package for doing that but for a different question, on [outlined characters](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25221/outlined-characters/25241#25241), I had an answer using the `contour` package that might create the effect you want.

Comment: Try http://www.1001freefonts.com/army-stencil-fonts.php.  I heard US Army in WWII used Amarillo font: http://www.dafont.com/amarillo-usaf.font

Comment: Same source said US Navy used Long Beach Font: http://www.tlai.com/images/lbusmp1.gif

Answer (score 3):

As noted in the comments to the question, there are many, many military stencil fonts freely available online. Once you've downloaded one you like, you can load it using the `fontspec` package and compile the `.tex` file with `xelatex` or `lualatex` instead of `pdflatex`.

In the example below, I've used a [freely available font](http://www.dafont.com/amarillo-usaf.font) and used `fontspec`'s `\newfontfamily` command to load it so that anything in the scope of `\stencil` (you could use any name for it you like) will be in that font. Everything else will be in the font loaded with the `\setmainfont` command.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Georgia}
\newfontfamily\stencil{AmarilloUSAF}

\begin{document}
Normal text

{\stencil Stencil text}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution with Plain XeTeX needing no packages. Once you have a suitable font installed<sup>1</sup>, it can be used directly in the plain format:

```
\font\stencil="OctinStencilRg-Regular"
Some stencil text: {\stencil M*A*S*H}\bye
```

[image]

---

<sup>1</sup> The font used here is [freely available](http://www.dafont.com/octin-stencil-free.font), but any OpenType stencil font will do.

Comment: Where's the MWE?!  `8^b`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes it's so minimal you might have missed it. ;-)

Comment: MCF = minimal code fragment... or maybe MWE = minimally written excerpt.

Comment: The 2 lines above are really a MWE for plain, just run xetex (*not* XeLaTeX) on it and you will see.