# Write text with negative color in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, color

There is probably no simple and general solution to this, but is it possible in `tikz` to write text in the negative color of the background, whatever the background?

To illustrative the problem (but I am not asking for a solution specific to *this* background):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\shade[left color=black,right color=red] (0,0) rectangle (4,2);
\node at (2,1) {this text is hard to read};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Negative is to be understood in any sense (complementary color, complementary to black), it does not really matter. The idea is to get something readable for any background.

**Edit** This is a comparison of the different methods suggested.

- First column: original (black text), 400 is not easy to read
- Second column: what I requested: not a good idea at all!
- Third column: white text with black contour: hardly readable when small
- Fourth column: black text on white background with `opacity`: my favorite
- Fifth column: white text in black background: I like it too, but slightly prefer the fourth one here because it's lighter.

[image]

Comment: Doesn't white do well in most instances?  (And black in the remaining ones?)  I'm not convinced that what you're asking for would look good or be necessarily legible.

Comment: @JPi White is generally worse, and the thing is this is generated by two loops, so it's cumbersome to manually change the color. But I agree that there are workarounds.

Comment: See section "23.3 Blend Modes" (p. 340, pgfmanual, v3.0.1a).

Comment: Use outlined texts (as subtitles) via the `contour` package to get better results.

Comment: ... for example, see [Outlined characters](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25221/14500).

Comment: While a manual choice of white or black often works, it's not always optimal, so this might be useful.  But consider that the negative of mid grey (#808080) is itself and you'll see where an overreliance on this automation would let you down.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The short answer is: use `blend modes` (p.340, pgfmanual v3.0.1a) with `difference` mode.

But, for better results, you may use *outlined text* or *background with opacity*. The following picture shows different tests:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (a) {\includegraphics{tiger}};

  \path (a.north) -- (a.south)
  \foreach \pos in {1,...,7}{coordinate[pos=\pos/8] (p-\pos)};

  \tikzset{my text/.style={text=white,font=\Huge\bfseries}}
  \def\mytext{Test of long text}

  \node[my text] (ex) at (p-1) {\mytext};
  \node[anchor=east] at (ex -| a.west) {white text};

  \node[my text,text=black](ex) at (p-2) {\mytext};
  \node[anchor=east] at (ex -| a.west) {black text};

  \node[my text,fill opacity=.5,fill=black,text opacity=1] (ex) at (p-3) {\mytext};
  \node[anchor=east] at (ex -| a.west) {black background with opacity};

  \node[my text,text=black,fill opacity=.5,fill=white,text opacity=1] (ex) at (p-4) {\mytext};
  \node[anchor=east] at (ex -| a.west) {white background with opacity};

  \node[my text] (ex) at (p-5) {\contour{white}{\mytext}};
  \node[anchor=east] at (ex -| a.west) {white outlined text};

  \node[my text] (ex) at (p-6) {\contour{black}{\textcolor{white}{\mytext}}};
  \node[anchor=east] at (ex -| a.west) {black outlined text};

  \begin{scope}[blend group=difference]
    \clip ($(p-7 -| a.west) + (0,1.1em)$) rectangle ($(p-7 -| a.east) + (0,-1.1em)$);
    \node {\includegraphics{tiger}};
    \node[my text] (ex) at (p-7) {\mytext};
  \end{scope}
  \node[anchor=east] at (ex -| a.west) {\emph{required} blended text (difference)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I find that a white background with opacity is almost always the way to go for such overlaid text

Comment: I am building a comparison of the different suggested methods; however, I cannot get the `blend mode` work with text, instead of fill or graphics. I did not find examples except with fading and patterns. Can this be done simply?

Comment: In my answer, the last example (the scope with the `blend group=difference` option) blends the text over the image.

Comment: @PaulGaborit I had forgotten `text=white`. Very useful answer which gathers most of the possibilities.

Answer (score 8):

A nonanswer : You are making a bad decision worse. First you don't need `t=` prefix because they are all t values. If you remove that you have the option to put a corner box with solid background with designated four character long width and one character long height

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{mwe} % <- for dummy images
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
cornerbox/.style 2 args={
  path picture={
    \node{\includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm]{#1}};
    \node[fill=black,text=white,
          minimum width=3ex,minimum height=1ex,
          anchor=north west,
          outer sep=0,font=\sffamily\tiny] 
          at (path picture bounding box.north west) {#2};
  },
  inner sep=0,
  minimum size=1cm
}
]

\node[cornerbox={example-image}{$\infty$},draw,thick] at (0,0) {};
\node[cornerbox={example-image-a}{200},draw,thick] at (1,0) {};
\node[cornerbox={example-image-b}{5000},draw,thick] at (2,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here you can make the annotation box as small as you wish, such that visually impaired and colorblinds can actually read your data.

[image]

Comment: You'd often be better showing the units than the symbol for the value being measured, but this wouldn't save much space.  If *t* is time though, I can't wait for the paper to come out given the ∞.

Comment: @ChrisH I agree but for grouped graphics, it is not a good idea to be pedantic about the conventions. It is the message that counts not correctness.

Comment: Yes, I think I'd put "t=10 s" in the first and 20, 30 or whatever in the subsequent boxes, so that the figure made sense on its own but with the fewest characters.  Or something like that

Comment: @ChrisH "t" is dimensionless, and I see no problem with t=\infty meaning the limit when t\to \infty, given that such a limit exists. Percusse's suggestion is nice, but a bit too invasive for the present purpose (I'll add a comparison when I managed to blend text and image).

Comment: @anderstood I'm used to lower-case t always being time, and my experiments take long enough as it is.

Comment: @ChrisH Here t is dimensionless time; the images are not from experiments but from numerical simulations. The thumbnails with t=\infty mean that there is no significant change between t=1000, t=10000, t=100000, etc. or in other word, that the numerical solution has converged to a stationnary solution. I agree that t=\infty would be strange in experimental work!

Answer (score 5):

Intriguing question, to which I don't know the answer.  However, you can mimic this effect doing something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand\fadingtext[3][]{%
    \begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=fading letter]
        \node[text=transparent!0,inner xsep=0pt,outer xsep=0pt,#1] {#3};
    \end{tikzfadingfrompicture}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(textnode.base)]
    \node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,#1](textnode){\phantom{#3}}; 
    \shade[path fading=fading letter,#2,fit fading=false]
    (textnode.south west) rectangle (textnode.north east);% 
    \end{tikzpicture}% 
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\shade[left color=black,right color=red] (0,0) rectangle (4,2) (2,1) node{\fadingtext{left color=white, right color=yellow}{this text is easier to read}};
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

**(example based on [another answer on this forum](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/192496/how-to-shade-text-in-different-colors))**

[image]

Comment: Yes, but I specifically asked for a general solution (i.e. without specifying the text colors) :)

Comment: Which is why I said that I didn't know the answer...