# How can I make a colored text with a black border in beamer?

Tags: beamer, color, framed

In beamer, how can I make a colored text with black boreder?

I am currently using \textcolor to have colored text, but I need a black border, so the text can be read more easily.

**EDIT** I want the border of the letter black I do not want this:

[image]

Comment: are you looking for `\fcolorbox{framecolor}{backgroundcolor}{text}` ?

Comment: @jfbu see my edit, please.

Comment: if you mean you want the outline of the characters black but filled with colour then that is not possible with the font formats used by pdftex, the vary latest opentype spec supports coloured fonts and there is some experimental luatex support for that, but as far as I know this version of luatex isn't in main distributions yet and there is no latex support for this "out of the box".  You could use pstricks.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes that is what I meant, thank you for the explanation

Comment: I would suggest ImageMagick for a very special and, of course, raster image, use. There `-fill` and `-stroke` options do what you aim to achieve.

Comment: have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25221/outlined-characters